# Warning when long pressing a key on the keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

Added a textfield and I got this warning in console whenever I press something too long on the keyboard

```
-[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UIRemoteKeyboardWindow: 0x1460f7e00; frame = (0 0; 414 896); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x283c7b0a0>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.
```

Any idea what is this warning and how to get rid of it?

Using Swift on XCode